# How to add a gap when splitting for joint in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks, cutting, joining

I drew a puzzle like joint sketch and split a body with it for 3d printing.

But I have to add a small gap between them for the tolerance of the machine.

Any way on how to do it not manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a thin cut extrude, instead of the "Split" tool.

Set this to be midplane, and add the total tolerance gap that you require depending on your printer, and how loose you want the puzzle pieces to be.

[image: Thin cut extrude]

Comment: Man you are great

Comment: Ya it created another problem that now the total length of the joined part is 1 mm short 
Guess i have to do 2 different drawings with 2 cuts :(
Unless you have another idea?

Comment: Can you include some photos to show what the exact problem you're having is now? If you do this and print it, then they are too close? So need more clearance on the 'peg' than on the vertical lines?

Comment: Yes,
added a photo

Comment: Ok, I see the photo but am still not sure what the problem is. How did it end up 1mm too short? Did you do a 1mm thick thin cut?

Comment: Yes, i want to cut just the joint not the entire line

Comment: Sounds like you want to do split and then add the clearance on the tabs only with thin cut then

Comment: It's that it use move face to offset the tabs to create the clearance